# getJSON using an external url

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to read an external JSON file with this script:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/geojson/1.0/hour',function( json ) {
//$.getJSON('hour',function( json ) {
    $.each( json.features, function( i, item ){
        alert(item.properties.mag);
    });
});
```

When I use the external url, this script doesn't work, however, when I use the local hour file (that I copied and pasted from the external url) this script works fine. Why?

Comment: [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: Cross-origin restrictions. Browsers don't let you send requests like that.

Comment: Hello Blender, is there any way to get the JSON string from that url?

Comment: use jsonp in general. Not sure about that particular URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to be "that guy" who actually posts another answer to this type of question. ***You can't do this due to the same origin policy (GOOGLE IT!)***

Actually, if you really need to do this, you can setup a proxy using PHP and use the proxy to obtain the necessary data.